# Swift scoping outside of a function

Tags: swift, scope, urlsession

I have a singleton URLSession that is parsing the response data into a dictionary. I want to use a single value from that dictionary in a subsequent piece of code, but cannot figure out how to pass the value out from the scope it's currently in.

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            debugPrint ("error: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        guard let content = data else {
            debugPrint("No data")
            return
        }
            guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
            debugPrint("Not containing JSON")
            return
        }
            if let idToken = json["id_token"] as? String {
                let privateToken = idToken;
                debugPrint("Gotten json response dictionary is \(idToken)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        return privateToken
```

Currently there is an IDE error on `return privateToken` saying that I am using an unresolved identifier: `privateToken`.

How can I take the string idToken and return it as a privateToken for use elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use a completion handler like:

```
func getPrivateToken(completion: @escaping(String) -> (), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            debugPrint ("error: \(error!)")
            failure(error)
            return
        }
        guard let content = data else {
            debugPrint("No data")
            failure(NSError(domain: "Your error message here.", code: 401, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
            debugPrint("Not containing JSON")
            failure(NSError(domain: "Your error message here.", code: 401, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        if let idToken = json["id_token"] as? String {
            completion(idToken)
            debugPrint("Gotten json response dictionary is \(idToken)")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And use it like so:

```
func exampleFunction() {
    self.getPrivateToken(completion: { (token) in
        // Do what ever you need with the token here.
        print("ID token is: \(token)")
    }) { (error) in
        // Present error here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer and I'll give it a shot, but I believe I would have to instantiate a second function within my bigger function, which may prove complicated.

Comment: The main problem with your example in your question is that the API call gets executed then it immediately tries to return a variable, but that variable equals nothing, because it is determined by an API call. Using something like a completion handler, in the example I provided, will wait until the call is finished, then return the variable.

Comment: Ohhhhhh that makes sense. Thanks.